# ejb3.1 @Startup.. @Singleton .. @PostConstruct read from XML the Objects

Tags: singleton, startup, ejb-3.1

I need to initialize a set of static String values stored in an XML files [ I know this is against the EJB spec ] 
as shown below  since the over all Idea is to not hardcore within EJB's the JNDI info

```
Utils.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<entry key="jndidb">java:jdbc/MYSQLDB10</entry>
<entry key="jndimdbque">java:jms/QueueName/remote</entry>
<entry key="jndi1">DBConnections/remote</entry>
<entry key="jndi2">AddressBean/remote</entry>
</properties>
```

The Onload of ejbserver startup code is as follows ...
inpstrem = clds.getClassLoaders(flename)  Reads the Util.xml and stores the same in Hashtable key value pare....

```
package com.ejb.utils;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.ConcurrencyManagement;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupUtils  {

private final String INITFILENAME      = "/System/Config/Utils.xml";  
private static Hashtable HTINITFLENME=null,HTERRINITFLENME=null,HTCMMNFLENME=null;

public StartupUtils() {
    HTINITFLENME = new Hashtable();
    HTERRINITFLENME = new Hashtable();
}

public void printAll(Hashtable htcmmnflenme){
    Enumeration ENUMK = null, VALS = null;
    String KEY = "", VALUE = "";
    ENUMK = htcmmnflenme.keys();         
    while (ENUMK.hasMoreElements()) {
        KEY = null;VALUE = null;
        KEY = (ENUMK.nextElement().toString().trim());
        VALUE = htcmmnflenme.get(KEY).toString().trim();
        InitLogDisplay(KEY +  " :::: " + VALUE);
    }
}

public static  void InitLogDisplay(String Datadisplay){
   System.out.println(Datadisplay); 
}

public Hashtable getDataProp(String flename){
    Map htData = null;
    InputStream inpstrem = null;        
    ClassLoaders clds = null;
    Enumeration enumk = null, vals = null;
    String key = "", value = "";
    Properties props = null;
    Hashtable htx = null;       
    try {
        clds = new ClassLoaders();          
        inpstrem = clds.getClassLoaders(flename);           
        props = new Properties();
        props.loadFromXML(inpstrem);                    
        enumk = props.keys();
        vals = props.elements();
        htData = new HashMap();
        htData = new TreeMap();
        while (enumk.hasMoreElements()) {
              key = (enumk.nextElement().toString().trim());
          value = (vals.nextElement().toString().trim());
          htData.put(key,value);                
        }
        clds = null;
        props = null;
        inpstrem.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
         key = ""; value = "";
         enumk = null;vals = null;
         clds=null;
         props=null;
         }
        htx = new Hashtable();
        htx.putAll(htData);
        return htx;
    }


    public void setUtilsPropDetails(){
        HTINITFLENME = getDataProp(INITFILENAME);
        this.printAll(HTINITFLENME);
    }

    public static Hashtable getUtilsPropDetails(){
        return HTINITFLENME;
    }

    @PostConstruct  
    public void startOnstartup(){       
      this.setUtilsPropDetails();
          this.printAll();          
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void startOnshutdown(){      
        try {
            this.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }   
}
```

On startup of EJB server  "this.printAll(HTINITFLENME);"  prints the key values of the XML file hoever If an external Call is made via any other EJB's to the method  "getUtilsPropDetails()"  does not return the key values....

Am i doing something wrong ??????

Comment: It sounds like you've encountered a bug.  The EJB spec explicitly requires the EJB container to block access to all EJBs in a module until all @Singleton @Startup beans have finished @PostConstruct.  (That said, I agree with Dave: use the standard refs/annotations and let the container do the work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the deployment descriptor and having the container do this work for you?

There are of course `<resource-ref>`, `<resource-env-ref>`, `<ejb-ref>` and `<env-entry>` elements to cover externally configuring which things should be made available to the bean for lookup.  For example:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>db</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <mapped-name>java:jdbc/MYSQLDB10</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>
```

I'm not sure how your vendor handles mapped-name (that particular element is vendor specific), but there will be an equivalent syntax to specify the datasource you want.

The singleton can then lookup `java:comp/env/db` and return the datasource to other EJBs.

If you are in a compliant Java EE 6 server, then you can change the name to `<res-ref-name>java:app/db</res-ref-name>` and then anyone in the app can lookup the datasource without the need to get it from the singleton.  Global JNDI is a standard feature of Java EE 6 and designed for exactly this.

You can put those elements in the ejb-jar.xml, web.xml or application.xml.  Putting them in the application.xml will make the one entry available to the entire application and give you one place to maintain everything.

Global resources can also be injected via:

```
@Resource(name="java:app/db")
DataSource dataSource;
```

If for some reason you didn't want to use those, at the very least you could use the `<env-entry>` element to externalize the strings.

### EDIT

See this other answer for a much more complete description of [JNDI as it pertains to simple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376730/can-resource-be-used-to-inject-primitives-in-ejb3-0/6382465#6382465).  This of course can be done where the name/value pairs are not simple types and instead are more complex types like `DataSource` and `Topic` or `Queue`

For example:

```
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>myDataSource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  </resource-ref>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>myJmsConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
  </resource-ref>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>myQueueCF</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
  </resource-ref>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>myTopicCF</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory</res-type>
  </resource-ref>
  <resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>myQueue</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.Queue</resource-env-ref-type>
  </resource-env-ref>
  <resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>myTopic</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.Topic</resource-env-ref-type>
  </resource-env-ref>
  <persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>myEntityManager</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>test-unit</persistence-unit-name>
  </persistence-context-ref>
  <persistence-unit-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>myEntityManagerFactory</persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>test-unit</persistence-unit-name>
  </persistence-unit-ref>
```

See the [JNDI and simple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376730/can-resource-be-used-to-inject-primitives-in-ejb3-0/6382465#6382465) answer for look and injection syntax.

### I see the name and type, but where's the value?

Configuring what actual things these names refer to has historically been done in a separate vendor specific deployment descriptor, such as `sun-ejb-jar.xml` or `openejb-jar.xml` or whatever that vendor requires.  The vendor-specific descriptor and the standard ejb-jar.xml descriptor combined provide the guaranteed portability apps require.

The `ejb-jar.xml` file offering only standard things like being able to say what types of resources the application requires and what names the application has chosen to use to refer to those resources.  The vendor-specific descriptor fills the gap of mapping those names to actual resources in the system.

As of EJB 3.0/Java EE 5, we on the spec groups departed from that slightly and added the `<mapped-name>` element which can be used in the `ejb-jar.xml` with any of the references shown above, such as `<resource-ref>`, to the vendor-specific name.  Mapped name will **never be portable** and its value will always be vendor-specific -- if it is supported at all.

That said, `<mapped-name>` can be convenient in avoiding the need for a separate vendor-specific file and achieves the goal of getting vendors-specific names out of code.  After all, the `ejb-jar.xml` can be edited when moving from one vendor to another and for many people that's good enough.

Comment: Hi Injecting the JNDI's for DB or Remote / Local should not be hadr coded .... This is the priliminary cause of using @startup of a Bena  ...Using EJB3 this is possible

Comment: ---continue So I have used aq XML file to store all the JNDI parms ( which can be later changed at run time if needed which has been replaced with static key's as example....  if "jndidb"  replace this key with java:jdbc/MYSQLDB10....but the problem with @Preconstruct  the static method  public static Hashtable getUtilsPropDetails(){return HTINITFLENME;} 
is not returning the Key value pair....   How to achieve the same..

Comment: I understand what you are saying perfectly.  The Java EE Expert Group was thinking the exact same thing when they created the "java:comp/env" namespace for standard and portable JNDI.  The problem is you've been using the JBoss specific names such as 'java:jdbc' which are not portable and bind your app too directly to the target system.  It's very smart of you to see that as bad and try to fix it.  But do understand that what you want exists, you just haven't been exposed to it yet.  All vendors are required to support the ability to remap "java:comp/env" names without requiring code change.

Comment: The objective of this XML file if u observer....
<entry key="jndidb">java:jdbc/MYSQLDB10</entry>  could be used across J2ee containers ,since they are simple key value pairs...and could be changed at every installation as required ... also the problem of duplicate JNDI could be solved...Hence need the bean to read the XML file in Singleton mode and store in  static Hashtable ...to be referenced by more then 1 clients across layers.... 
MYSQL <entry key="jndidb">java:jdbc/MYSQLDB10</entry>

Comment: Sorry I haven't had time to follow up.  I wrote this other answer with you in mind and hope you find it useful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376730/can-resource-be-used-to-inject-primitives-in-ejb3-0/6382465#6382465