# Resource injection and resolution

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi

I'm using WildFly 8.1 application server and need to obtain EJB which is located on remote GlassFish server. What kind of options do I have? What I was thinking about is to manually create InitialContext, provide necessary properties like GlassFish addres etc. Is there any better solution? Can I obtain this EJB through annotation like @Resource?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should answer your question:

> Client access to an enterprise bean that implements a remote business
>   interface is accomplished through either dependency injection or JNDI
>   lookup.
>
> To obtain a reference to the remote business interface of an
>   enterprise bean through dependency injection, use the javax.ejb.EJB
>   annotation and specify the enterprise bean’s remote business interface
>   name:
>
> @EJB Example example; To obtain a reference to a remote business
>   interface of an enterprise bean through JNDI lookup, use the
>   javax.naming.InitialContext interface’s lookup method:
>
> ExampleRemote example = (ExampleRemote)
>           InitialContext.lookup("java:global/myApp/ExampleRemote");

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first answer, it's important to note that the remote EJB *must* implement an `@Remote` interface:

```
  @Remote
  public interface RemoteEJB
```

Given the above implementation on the remote EJB, you could just have the following in your remote client:

```
  @EJB
  RemoteEJB remoteEJB;
```

> Can I obtain this EJB through annotation like @Resource?

I don't believe you can. `@Resource` is best used for ancillary artifacts like `javax.sql.DataSource`s, JMS message queues and JavaMail sessions.

---

**Tip:** Using the `InitialContext` is more expensive in JNDI lookups. [According to this answer by a member of the Java EE Expert Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376730/can-resource-be-used-to-inject-primitives-in-ejb3-0), using the `SessionContext` gives better performance in looking up context resources.